# Laravel 5 many middlewares and performance

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, middleware

My app have a few middlewares that get run on every request.

I'm wondering the performance impact of having many middleware.  Is it just a function call or is it doing a HTTP redirect when one middleware get pass to another.

It is possible for me to join all the middlewares to a single middleware but for modularity, I've separated the middleware to perform a specific task.

Answer (score 1):

I was just going through the Middleware docs and I founded this:

*HTTP middleware provide a convenient mechanism for filtering HTTP requests entering your application. For example, Laravel includes a middleware that verifies the user of your application is authenticated. If the user is not authenticated, the middleware will redirect the user to the login screen. However, if the user is authenticated, the middleware will allow the request to proceed further into the application.*

and according to me, it doesn't redirect every time unless and until there is failure in condition. So, according to me there won't be performance issue.

Answer (score 1):

Middlewares are just a recursrsive chain of function calls. The first middleware calls the second, which calls the third, and so on.

If one of the middlewares chooses to redirect or some other request-destructive action, the chain is terminated. (For instance the authentication middleware will redirect if the user is not authenticated)

If none of the middlewares break the chain, the recursive tail is rolled back up and the request is proceeded into the application.

**Edit**:
Here's a very simple example of a middle ware: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.0/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php#L35

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($this->app->isDownForMaintenance())
    {
        throw new HttpException(503);
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

You see the handle method gets the `$request` as an argument, and a Closure that points to the `$next` middle ware's `handle` method.

You can see that (in this case) unless the application is in maintenance mode, it just calls the next middle ware in the chain with (the possibly altered) request.

Answer (score 0):

Middleware is simply a piece of code that gets executed on every request. As far as I know, it does not interfere with your request cycle as in creating HTTP redirects unless your middleware is doing that explicitly. The most basic flow for middleware execution is

```
request -> middleware-1 -> middleware-2 ... middleware-N -> controller action -> response
```

Logically, as you add more middleware, more code gets executed upon every request so yes, I think it may impact your application performance but to find out exactly how much the impact is, you will have to benchmark your code with and without middleware. Also, middleware helps you filter requests. If a certain middleware stops the request from propagating further into your application, very little code gets executed so you also have to keep in mind not all requests execute the same amount of code. In other words, in above figure, if a certain condition fails in middleware-1, rest of the middleware plus controller code is not even executed and the response is returned immediately.

As for having specialized objects for each middleware, I would say yes, that should be your approach since Laravel 5's architecture encourages that and it also makes your middleware modular(re-usable in other applications).

Comment: thanks.  once I have more free time I'll do some benchmarking.